# Android Voice Recognition API

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am developing an app that requires the voice recognition to stay 
active for an entire minute. Upon reviewing the docs, I discovered 
"SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS" added to 2.2. However 
Google's default voice recognition service doesn't seem to support it. Does anybody know a way 
that I could force voice recognition to last a minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow I hate crappy documentation. Apparently Google's voice recognition service does support SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, but requires the input to be a long. Of course if you put in an integer when adding the extra, it will call the method looking for an int. Then it will throw a very nasty silent error. Just make sure you cast the number as a long, and the world will be good.